# Data pipeline error when exporting RDS to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

I am using the RDStoS3CopyActivity template and keep getting this error when trying to export data from Aurora to S3.

```
amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskExecutionException: Error copying record
at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.processAll(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:65)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.runActivity(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:35)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.CopyActivity.runActivity(CopyActivity.java:22)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.objects.AbstractActivity.run(AbstractActivity.java:16)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeRemoteRunner(TaskPoller.java:136)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeTask(TaskPoller.java:105)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller$1.run(TaskPoller.java:81)
at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.executeWork(PollWorker.java:76)
at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.run(PollWorker.java:53)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: DriverClass not found for database:aurora
at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.database.RdsHelper.getDriverClass(RdsHelper.java:24)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getRdsDatabaseConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:157)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:73)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnectionWithCredentials(ConnectionFactory.java:301)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.createConnection(SqlDataNode.java:100)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.getConnection(SqlDataNode.java:94)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.prepareStatement(SqlDataNode.java:162)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlInputConnector.open(SqlInputConnector.java:48)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlInputConnector.<init>(SqlInputConnector.java:25)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.getInputConnector(SqlDataNode.java:79)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.processAll(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:47)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error it was because I was using the RdsDatabase it needs to be the JdbcDatabase when using Aurora.

```
"type": "JdbcDatabase",
"connectionString": "jdbc:mysql://thing-master.cpbygfysczsq.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/db_name",
"jdbcDriverClass" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
```